# "locate" Linux command alternative for mac OSX

Tags: linux, bash, macos, command-line, terminal

In Linux, we can use the `locate` command to find the files from the terminal. 
Is there any command available for Mac OSX which works same as the `locate` command?

I want to find a file in complete filesystem accessible by User(Me) in mac OSX. Can it be done with some command from the terminal?

This command should show me the list of all paths where the file of the same name is available.

Comment: Have you tried `find` ?

Comment: I think, find command works only for the current directory.

Comment: Please give me example command if you know how to search the whole filesystem with find command.

Comment: Or even, `locate`?  That command originated in 4.4BSD, was introduced to FreeBSD in version 2.2, and has been included in every version of OS X. Also, this is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not a programming question.

Comment: The service that builds the database for `locate` isn't running by default, although running `locate` gives you instructions for starting it.

Comment: This is not the off-topic for StackOverflow. This is completely appropriate question for the included tags.  You can find most voted questions which doesn't include code but those are really important for coding or any other programmer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: It doesn't belong only to apple community because to know its answer someone should know how locate command work which is the part of linux community

Comment: `locate` is _not_ a Linux command and is included in OSX as much as it is included in Linux - perhaps not active by default, for more info, please consult [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188799/cannot-locate-app-locate-not-working) and [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228164/is-there-a-way-to-use-update-command-to-locate-files-on-os-x-without-having-to-r) AskDifferent post, where this question might have a better chance.

Comment: I agree but linux users are much more familiar with this command.

Comment: Use **findy**: https://github.com/f1lt3r/findy... `npm install findy -g`, `findy '**/notes.txt'`

Comment: Why won't you try activating locate on mac os?

    ```sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I guess the `mdfind` command is what your are looking for:

```
mdfind -name test.pdf
```

Comment: mdfind does not find dot-files though.